# Icons in the Text Field doesn't work Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, icons

Prefix and suffix icons in the Text field doesn't work.
Only an X inside a box is shown.
Icons work everywhere else.

[image: suffixIcon]

[image: prefixIcon]

I have imported the Cupertino package also:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
```

Version:

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
```

My Code:

```
Container(
    height: 55.0,
    child:
    TextField(
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: new Icon(Icons.search),
            fillColor: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
            filled: true,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            hintText: 'Search',
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

I don't get any errors also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For it looks like you are using the wrong Icons library. Maybe you could check to use CupertinoIcons instead of Icons.

If I am correct the Icons is material, and the CupertinoIcons is from iOS.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73243
See the code of this issue.